# Change Spring profile at runtime

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-boot, profile

I'm wondering if there's any change to change a Spring profile at runtime, without restarting the whole application.
When I say change a Spring profile, I mean to remove the actual profile and add another one, then reload all the Spring Beans that uses the old profile to use now the new profile.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think even JRebel can do that.

Comment: No as you will need to reload the context, which is basically the same as restarting your application.